# Como puedo acceder a mi toolbar desde un fragment para ocultarla.?

Tags: android-fragment

Hola se me esta presentando un error de nullPointerException al querer esconder mi toolbar
En mi desarrollo tengo los siguiente.
Tengo una toolbar declarada en un layout xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

En el fragment estoy tratando de llamar a la toolbar utilizando el metodo getActivity() pero cuando ejecuto la aplicacion pareciera que no logra encontrar mi activity, que puedo hacer para encontrar las instancia de mi actividad?

```
this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar).findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
```

Al momento de iniciar el fragment la app crashea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una instancia singleton para que te permita acceder a la activity que contiene ese fragment. basicamente debes de regresar en el arbol hacia el activity. Puedes tener algo asi en tu clase singleton.

```
public static void setCurrentActivity(AppCompatActivity arg){currentAcivity=arg;}
public static void getCurrentActivity(){return currentActivity;}
```

puedes declarar tu activity como estatica en tu clase singleton y despues acceder a ella en el fragment en donde la requieres

```
Singleton.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar).findviewById(R.id.botonbuscado);
```